# Make pga tag a synonym of programmable-gain-amplifier tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Yesterday I created [programmable-gain-amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programmable-gain-amplifier) (and added the tag info for it) after I answered a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/548762/51760) yesterday about such an amplifier which used [pga](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pga). There are a few [questions which use the shorter tag](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pga) and which could/should be tagged with the new, longer one. I could edit these questions individually in order to change the tags on all of them, but since "PGA" is a common acronym it seems likely that users will continue to tag questions about PGAs with [pga](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pga). Therefore it seems like a good idea to make [pga](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pga) a synonym of [programmable-gain-amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programmable-gain-amplifier). However, I cannot suggest this synonym (I don't have a score of 5 on the tag), and in my experience tag synonym suggestions tend not to be reviewed for a long time (if ever) since they are on a [separate page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested).

Would a moderator kindly merge the tags and make them synonyms, with [programmable-gain-amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programmable-gain-amplifier) the master tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good idea, The tags are now merged